# Laravel Carbon Group by Month

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

I'm trying to output all the months but group them so they are unique.

```
$months = NewsItem::select(DB::raw('MONTH("created_at") as month'))->groupBy('month')->get();
return $months;
```

I'm getting the following back

```
{"month":null}
```

In my database I have five news articles all created_at 05/01/2017 so it's right that I only get one response but I'm not getting the number of the month back?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use `groupBy()` method with closure:

```
 $months = NewsItem::groupBy(function($d) {
     return Carbon::parse($d->created_at)->format('m');
 })->get();
```

Or get data first and then use `groupBy()` on the Eloquent collection:

```
 $months = NewsItem::get()->groupBy(function($d) {
     return Carbon::parse($d->created_at)->format('m');
 });
```

Comment: Hi, this is giving me strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given error.

Comment: You have to use second method.First Get and then groupby

Answer (score 3):

Why do you need the group by clause in your usecase?

You are not fetching any additional data for which a group by is required, you just want to have a list of distinct months, so use distinct.

```
$months = NewsItem::selectRaw("MONTH(created_at) as month")->distinct()->get();
```

Also looking at the solution provided by Alexey, you'll need to fetch the entire dataset from the DB, which is highly inefficient looking at what you are trying to do. A `distinct()` query would be much faster than a `select *` and group the results in PHP.

Edit:

Little sidenote here, the reason you get `null` returned as value is because you use a string in the `MONTH()` function instead of the actual field.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply using groupby and mysql MONTH.

```
$months = NewsItem::groupby(\DB::raw('MONTH(created_at) as month'))->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```
NewsItem::get(["*",\DB::raw('MONTH(created_at) as month')])->groupBy('month');
```

Answer (score 0):

To get earnings on monthly basis you can try the below code:-

```
$getMonthlyReport = OrderMaster::select(DB::raw("sum(order_total_amt) as        earnings,date_format(order_date, '%Y-%m') as YearMonth"))
    ->groupBy('order_date')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$month = NewsItem::select(
DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%M") as month'))
->groupBy('month')
->get();
```