# Laravel Eloquent Get grouped by Relation Data

Tags: laravel, group-by, eloquent, model, relation

I am trying to get data with eager loading grouped by relation. Means, I want to eager load the relation in group by of a column. I have tried this code,

```
$customer = Customer::with(['orders' => function($query) {
        $query->groupBy('shop_id');
    }])->where('id', $id)->get();
```

Here the DB relation is,

> Customer Has Many Orders (One to Many)

As an example, if I want to groupBy `shop_id`, I am expecting data in below format:

```
customer1 => 
    otherProperties,
    orders =>[
        shop_id1 => [
            order1,
            order2 ...
        ],
        shop_id2 => [
            order5
        ]
    ]
```

But I am getting normal eager loaded data, like,

```
customer1 => 
    otherProperties,
    orders => [
       order1,
       order2,
       order5,
    ]
```

Can anyone help me in this regard? 
I can achieve similar result using raw query or php. But how I can achieve this using eloquent?

Comment: Is your created_at a default timestamp created with migration? If so, it look like this ```2016-09-21 18:50:26```. So, if your customer's order are saved at the exact same second into the DB, you'll never have 2 orders in the same bag. You can take a look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41483365/laravel-carbon-group-by-month

Comment: Here, I used `created_at` only for demonstration. In actual I was using different column. I am updating my question. I just used `created_at` for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

The groupBy happen on the collection and not on the query itself.

**First suggestion : Create a custom scope**

You could create a custom scope into your model with some Raw expressions : https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#raw-expressions . Then, you will be able to do this:

```
$customer = Customer::with('newScope')->find($id);
```

> Did you know that `$customer = Customer::where('id', $id)->get()`
>   return a collection of model and `$customer = Customer::find($id)`
>   return a single model?
>
> ```
> $customer = Customer::where('id', $id)->get();
> $customer = { [0] => {data} };
>
> $customer = Customer::find($id);
> $customer = { data };
> ```

**Second suggestion : Use groupBy on the collection after the query**

```
$customer = Customer::with('orders')->find($id);
$customer->orders = $customer->orders->groupBy('shop_id'));
```