# how to get the total number of registered users per month in an eloquent query with laravel 7?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

I need help in the following ... I want to graph the result of the query ... I am using the consoleTVCharts library for it ... but I have problems when graphing the results
this is the code of my query:

```
$users = User::select(\DB::raw("COUNT(*) as count"))
    ->whereYear('created_at' ,'=', '2020')
    ->groupBy(\DB::raw("Month(created_at)"))
    ->pluck('count');
```

the code to create the graph

```
$chart4 = new RegistroUsuariosMensual;
    $chart4->title('Total User Monthly');
    $chart4->labels(['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']);
    $chart4->dataset('meses','line',$users);
```

and this is the result
[image]

and in my database I have no registered users in those months
[image]

what will be the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel Carbon Group by Month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41483365/laravel-carbon-group-by-month)

Answer (score 0):

You can't user groupBy in a integer number, try this

```
$users = User::select(\DB::raw('strftime("%m", created_at) as month, count(id) as total'))
->whereBetween('created_at', ['2020-01-01 00:00:00', '2020-12-31 23:59:59'])
->groupBy('month')
->orderBy('month')
->pluck('total', 'month')
->all();
```